# monte carlo error induced by a sampling pattern

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, sampling-theory

Assume we want to estimate $$I=\int f(x):{\rm d}x=\hat f(0).$$ This can be done by an estimator of the form $$\tilde I=\sum_iw_if(x_i).$$ Introducing the "sampling function" $$S(x)=\sum_iw_i\delta(x-x_i),$$ this estimator can be expressed as $$\tilde I=\int Sf=\widehat{Sf}(0)=\left(\hat S\ast\hat f\right)(0)=\langle\hat S,\hat f\rangle_{L^2}.$$ The error of the estimation is $\tilde I-I$.

> Now, I've read that the following and don't really understand what's actually meant. If the sampling pattern sums to $1$ (I guess it's meant that $\sum_iw_i=1$), then the error is the dot product between the spectrum of $f$ and the spectrum of $S$ where the DC is replaced by zero. If the sampling pattern doesn't sum to $1$, then the error has an additional term, which is the true integral multiplied by the difference between
> the DC of the sampling pattern and one.

Could anybody express in mathematical formulas what's actually meant by this? The statements can be found on p. 4 of [this paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Frequency-Analysis-of-Monte-Carlo-and-other-Durand/54c53cfd94824d5ec4ff03e16691187f4fd93ede).